# Differential equation question

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following differential equation $(1+xy)ydx + (1-xy)xdy=0$.

I have been taught to solve differential equations of the following type:

1.Homogeneous

2.Variable separable

3.Linear differential equation

But, I'm unable to find to which category the given differential equation belongs.Please help. I would like some hints towards solving the question and **please** don't post the answer.

Comment: Is your expression equal to something ?

Comment: One of the $dy$ terms should be a $dx$. Then presumably this is an exact differential equation.

Comment: Sorry for the typo...I was just getting mad trying to solve this question.

Comment: Good luck ! It is just awful to me !

Comment: hmm, it's not quite exact after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $\xi = xy$, $\eta = \frac{x}{y}$. Then
$$\begin{align}
\mathrm{d}\xi &= y\,\mathrm{d}x + x\,\mathrm{d}y
& \mathrm{d}\eta &= \frac{y\,\mathrm{d}x - x\,\mathrm{d}y}{y^2}
\end{align}$$
And therefore
$$\mathrm{d}\xi + \frac{\xi^2}{\eta}\mathrm{d}\eta = 0$$
I suppose, you can take it from there.

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer. While manipulating the given differential equation I didn't have the insight towards making it into this form that you have made. Does that insight come through more practice?

Comment: Of course, over time (with practice) one learns to recognize such patterns. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

$$(1+xy)ydx+(1-xy)xdy=0$$
The given equation is of the form $f_1(xy)ydx+f_2(xy)xdy=0$
.Here, $$M=(1+xy)y$$  $$ N=(1-xy)x$$
$$\therefore I.F.=\frac1{Mx-Ny}=\frac1{2x^2y^2}$$
$\therefore\text{the solution is}$
$$\int_{(\text {y const})}M\times(I.F.)dx+\int (\text{terms of N not containing x})\times(I.F.)dy=c$$
I think you can take help from this..

Answer (score -1):

If you have anything of form $$f(xy)y \text{ d}x + g(xy)x \text{ d}y = 0 $$then I.F. will be $$\frac{1}{Mx-Ny}$$ Multiply this to make it exact differential equation.

Comment: Your method would work, add more details.